# Grails group by date

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class with a date-property.

```
class Transaction {
    LocalDate time
    BigDecimal amount
}
```

How can I query for the sum of all transactions grouped by month? I can´t find any support for group by a date-range in GORM.

Comment: I don't know any GORM specific functions but if its ok for you - you could use database specific functions. I've used `GROUP BY MONTH(time)` for MySQL so far.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add a formula based field to your domain class for the truncated date:

```
class Transaction {
    LocalTime time
    BigDecimal amount
    String timeMonth

    static mapping = {
        timeMonth formula: "FORMATDATETIME(time, 'yyyy-MM')" // h2 sql
        //timeMonth formula: "DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m')"   // mysql sql
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to run queries like this:

```
Transaction.withCriteria {
    projections {
        sum('amount')
        groupProperty('timeMonth')
    }
}
```

Comment: Attention: When using CamelCase for domain properties you have to use underscore for the field name in sql syntax. e.g. datePhotoTaken will result in date_photo_taken

Comment: @timeMonth whether the property timeMonth will get mapped in db

Comment: @Suganthan The property is not mapped in db but you have to add `timeMonth nullable: true` in constraints to avoid validation errors.

Comment: @César Thank you, but it is in domain class right, so whether timeMonth having a special reservation in grails

Comment: @ataylor, I tried this code by I am getting exception: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: week of: <myClass>, I am using grails 2.3.x

Comment: @an5607ky, there is no property `week` in the example.  Why not ask a new question including your code?

Comment: I have asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556773/how-to-set-formula-in-grails-domain-class