# Group by week / month / year in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class (minified) as :-

```
class Expense {
    Date dateOfExpense
    int amount
}
```

I am trying to get sum of amount grouped by week/month/ year of expense date.
Referring to 'sqlGroupProjection' method in grails doc http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html,

I tried using following code:-

```
def results = c {
    between("dateOfExpense", fromDate, toDate)              
    projections {
         sqlGroupProjection 'dateOfExpense,sum(amount) as summed',       
        'MONTH(dateOfExpense)',['date','summed'],[DATE,NUMBER]                  
    }
}
```

Throws exception:

```
 No such property: DATE for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder. Stacktrace follows:
 Message: No such property: DATE for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder
```

Please suggest an approach using `sqlGroupProjection` method

Comment: Can you please answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604309/how-to-write-between-clause-for-from-to-dates-for-createcriteria-in-grails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create three new numeric fields each for week,month and year in the domain class. These fields won't be mapped to column in the table.
2. Provide static mapping for the three fields.

   ```
   static mapping = {
        //provide the exact column name of the date field
        week formula('WEEK(DATE_OF_EXPENSE)')    
        month formula('MONTH(DATE_OF_EXPENSE)')
        year formula ('YEAR(DATE_OF_EXPENSE)')
   }
   ```

Now we can group by desired field using

```
def results = c.list {
  between("dateOfExpense", fromDate, toDate) 
  projections {
    switch(groupBy){
        case "week":
           groupProperty('year')
           groupProperty('month')
           groupProperty('week') 
        break;
        case "month"
           groupProperty('year')
           groupProperty('month')
        break;
        case "year":
           groupProperty('year')
        break;
    }        
    sum('amount')
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but getting error: could not resolve property: dayOfWeeo of: myClass. what to do?

Comment: error: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: week of: myClass

Comment: Did you follow the step 2 ?

Comment: yeah, I have provided fields with formula. like :     
        month formula('MONTH(appointment_time)')
        year formula('YEAR(appointment_time)')
        day formula('DAYOFMONTH(appointment_time)')

Comment: Can you please answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604309/how-to-write-between-clause-for-from-to-dates-for-createcriteria-in-grails

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
static mapping = {

week formula('WEEK(DATE_OF_EXPENSE)')    //provide the exact column name of the date field
month formula('MONTH(DATE_OF_EXPENSE)')
year formula ('YEAR(DATE_OF_EXPENSE)')

}
```

try this

```
static mapping = {

week formula: 'WEEK(DATE)'    
month formula: 'MONTH(DATE)'
year formula: 'YEAR(DATE)'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
sqlGroupProjection 'MONTH(dateOfExpense) as month, sum(amount) as summed',
    'month',['month','summed'],[NUMBER,NUMBER]
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. 
Now its giving exception:-
    No such property: NUMBER for class: grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder

The grails doc says the fourth argument should be list of org.hibernate.type.Type 

How do we adhere to that?

Answer (score 0):

This `sqlGroupProjection` method seems to be poorly supported. Use

```
def results = c.list {
    between("dateOfExpense", fromDate, toDate) 
    projections {
        groupProperty('dateOfExpense')
        sum('amount')
    }
}
```

will produce the deserved outcome.

If you want group by the month of the date, see [Grails group by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455409/grails-group-by-date) (It totally outweight my answer, actually. But I reach the same solution after trying your code for a long time.)

Comment: Simply using groupProperty('dateOfExpense') won't solve the purpose as it will try to group exact date till mill sec level. 

Approach suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455409/grails-group-by-date

solved by problem.

Comment: Refer to my answer to this question.

Comment: Can you please answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28604309/how-to-write-between-clause-for-from-to-dates-for-createcriteria-in-grails